# db4o error "Unexpected char '@'"

Tags: c#, db4o

DB4O appears to be chocking on a string that has the "@" symbol in it. The error message I am getting is "Unexpected char '@'." Does anyone know what causes this? I've done research on Google and did not find any work arounds or explanations for the behavior.

Comment: Yes, code would be nice. And what version of db4o are you using? Are you using an embedded server or client/server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception was actually being caused by the name of the assembly. Any char like `&`, `:` or `@` causes db4o to fail, even though .NET doesn't seem to mind the `@` in the assembly name.